# Que es recomendable para guardar datos de tipo imagen y de texto en una sola tabla o en distintas

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando una aplicación android, en una categoría llamada rutas o puntos  de evacuación de un terremoto tengo que subir una imagen de un mapa con marcadores el cual sera marcado de manera manual de las ubicaciones de albergues y una lista con nombres de sus rutas o puntos de evacuación, esto es para los usuarios que puedan ver esa informacion y sepan que ruta es la mas cerca a evacuar , esto pensado en crear una base de datos, pero cual es considerable crea una tabla solo para la imagen y en otra tabla para las rutas o en una sola tabla tener los datos tanto como de la imagen y rutas, ya que el administrador registrara el nombre del estado o municipio, la imagen y  los nombres de las rutas de cada marcador, y también poder modificar.

**La vista quedaría mas o menos así en la app**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla evacuacion**

```
CREATE TABLE t_evacuacion(
id int auto_increment primary key,
nombreEstado varchar(40) not null,
imagenEstado varchar(80) not null,
nombreRuta varchar(100) not null
 );
```

Comment: Tendrás que hacerte un modelo (con papel y lápiz) y si la relación es de muchos a muchos tendrás que llevar varias tablas, sino en una... Eso depende de lo que tengas que hacer...

Comment: ¿En qué, con qué o cómo se relacionan una imagen y una ruta?

Comment: @Sal la imagen se creara manualmente marcado cada ruta por medio de Google Earth y la descripción de cada ruta se hará como en una lista, ya edite mi pregunta para ver si me doy a entender un poco mas.

Comment: no suena muy eficiente crear la imagen manualmente, recortarla y almacenarla. Lo usual sería dibujar tanto la cartografía como los vectores (rutas, markers y labels) analíticamente, de modo que en BBDD está solamente el arreglo de coordenadas del linestring o multilinestring que define una ruta, y la aplicación que consume esa información se preocupa de dibujarlas. Perfectamente pueden coexistir dos aplicaciones leyendo de la misma BBDD y cada una dibujar con técnicas distintas